# Async await unit testing issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, async-await

This is the `update` function I want to test in mocked database

```
import Book from '../model/book';

function bookRepository(db) {
    this.db = db;
};

bookRepository.prototype.update = async function(id, data) {
    return await Book.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, { $set: data });
}

export default bookRepository;
```

This is test script I wrote for it

```
import chai from 'chai';
import chaiAsPromised from 'chai-as-promised';
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
const expect = chai.expect;

import app from '../../server';
import bookRepo from '../../repository/book';
const Book = new bookRepo(app.db);

describe('Test repository: book', () => {

    describe('update', () => {
        let id;
        beforeEach(async() => {
            let book = {
                name: 'Records of the Three Kingdoms',
                type: 'novel',
                description: 'History of the late Eastern Han dynasty (c. 184–220 AD) and the Three Kingdoms period (220–280 AD)',
                author: 'Luo Guanzhong',
                language: 'Chinese'
            };
            let result = await Book.insert(book);
            id = await result.id;
            return;
        });
        it('Update successfully', async() => {
            let data = {
                type: 'history',
                author: 'Chen Shou'
            };
            let result = await Book.update(id, data);
            await expect(result).to.be.an('object');
            await expect(result.type).to.be.equal('history');
            return expect(result.author).to.be.equal('Chen Shou');
        });
    });

});
```

And I received this error

```
AssertionError: expected 'novel' to equal 'history'
      + expected - actual
```

When I check the mocked database, it does update data, but why does its assertion fail? It should have already updated after completing `await` call

Comment: What does `console.log(result)` give you?

Comment: @lonesomeday Exactly the same with `book` as if it hasn't get updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `findOneAndUpdate` method takes `options` as the third argument. One of the options is `returnNewDocument: <boolean>`. This is `false` by default. If you don't set this option as `true` then MongoDB updates the document and returns the old document as a result. If you set this option to `true` then MongoDB returns the new updated document.

From the official docs -

> Returns either the original document or, if returnNewDocument: true, the updated document.

So in your update method, make the following change -

```
return await Book.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, { $set: data }, { returnNewDocument : true });
```

You can read about it [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/).

**Edit** -  If using `mongoose` then use the `{new: true}` option instead of the above option as `mongoose` uses the `findAndModify` underneath the `findOneAndUpdate` method.

Comment: Thank you very much.Just a little bit modification in your answer, the right option is:  ```{ new: true}```

Comment: @necroface I suppose you're using `mongoose`. The documentation I provided is for the native MongoDB driver :) I'll mention that in the answer.